# promise and jquery validation are not working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, promise, jquery-validate

As you can see below, I have a modal that should be validated then send a request to the server. The problem is that if I try to submit for the first time, that validation is worked properly but for the second time it won't work. When I debug the codes  I found out that `validationCheck()` worked fine but the `resolve()` doesn't return any result to the `add()` in `certificate-manager` file.

request.js

```js
let insert = function (isPost = false, url, data, reloadLocation = false, table = null,
                       modal = null, ponds) {


    let request = null;
    if (isPost) {
        let uploadNotify = uploadNotification();

        //step 3
        let config = {

            onUploadProgress: function (progressEvent) {
                let percentCompleted = Math.round((progressEvent.loaded * 100) / progressEvent.total);
                console.log(percentCompleted);
                uploadNotify.update('message', '<strong>Uploading</strong> ' + percentCompleted + ' %');
                uploadNotify.update('progress', percentCompleted);
            },
            headers: {
                'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
            }
        };

        //step 4
        request = axios.post(url, data, config)

    } else {
        //step 4
        request = axios.get(url, {
            params: data
        });
    }

    request.then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        let data = response['data'];

        if (data['status'] === 200) {
            let content = {
                'title': 'Done!',
                'message': data['message']

            };
            notification(content, 1);
            if (reloadLocation)
                location.reload();
            if (table) {
                table.ajax.reload();
                clearModal('.inp', ponds);
            }
        }
    })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
            let data = error['data'];
            let content = {
                'title': 'Error!',
                'message': data['message']

            };
            notification(content, 0);

        })
        .then(function () {
            if (modal)
                closeModal(modal);
        });


};
```

utilities.js

```js
async function validationCheck (id, rules) {
    jQuery.validator.addMethod('passwordCheck', function (value, element, param) {
        //Your Validation Here
        let oldPass = jQuery('#input-old-password').val();
        let confirmPass = jQuery('#input-confirm-password').val();

        return oldPass != null && confirmPass === value;

        // return bool here if valid or not.
    }, 'Your error message!');

    jQuery.validator.addMethod('phoneNumber', function (value, element, param) {
        value = value.replace(/\s+/g, "");
        return this.optional(element) || value.length > 9 &&
            value.match(/\(?([0-9]{3})\)?([ .-]?)([0-9]{3})\2([0-9]{4})/);
    }, 'Please specify a valid phone number');

    jQuery.validator.addMethod('startDate', function (value, element, param) {
        return (parseInt(value) > 2000)
    }, 'Please specify a valid year');

    jQuery.validator.addMethod('endDate', function (value, element, param) {
        return (parseInt(value) >= parseInt(jQuery('#input-start-time').val()) ||
            jQuery('#input-current').is(":checked"))
    }, 'Please specify a valid year');

    jQuery.validator.addMethod('uendDate', function (value, element, param) {
        return (parseInt(value) >= parseInt(jQuery('#input-update-start-time').val()) ||
            jQuery('#input-update-current').is(":checked"))
    }, 'Please specify a valid year');


    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=> {
        jQuery(id).validate({
            // define validation rules
            rules: rules,
            errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                let group = element.closest('.input-group');
                if (group.length) {
                    group.after(error.addClass('invalid-feedback'));
                } else {
                    element.after(error.addClass('invalid-feedback'));
                }
            },
            // messages: {
            //     username: {
            //         required: "Username is required"
            //     }
            // },
            //display error alert on form submit
            invalidHandler: function (event, validator) {
                // let alert = jQuery('#kt_form_1_msg');
                // alert.removeClass('kt--hide').show();
                KTUtil.scrollTo(id, -200);
                reject(false);

            },

            submitHandler: function (form) {
                resolve(true);
                //form[0].submit(); // submit the form
            }
        });



    });

}
```

certificate-manager.js

```js
let add = async function () {
    let check = await validationCheck("#form", {
        title: {
            required: true
        },
        company: {
            required: true
        },
        start: {
            required: true,
            date: true,
            digits: true,
            minlength: 4,
            maxlength: 4,
            startDate: true

        },
        end: {
            date: true,
            digits: true,
            minlength: 4,
            maxlength: 4,
            endDate: true

        },
        description: {
            required: true

        }
    }).then(value => {
        console.log(value)
        insert(
            false,
            '/api/add/certificate',
            getInputsData(),
            false,
            table,
            "#kt_modal")
    }, reason => {
        console.log(reason)
    }).catch(reason => {
        console.log(reason)
    });


}
```

```html
     <!--begin:: insert Modal-->
        <div class="modal fade" id="kt_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
             aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">New Certificate</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <form id="form">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-12">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="input-title"
                                               class="form-control-label">Title</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="inp form-control"
                                               name="title"
                                               id="input-title">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="input-company-institute"
                                               class="form-control-label">Company/Institute</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="inp form-control" name="company" id="input-company-institute">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="form-group col-6">
                                            <label for="input-start-time"
                                                   class="form-control-label">From Year</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="inp form-control" name="start" id="input-start-time">
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="form-group  col-6">
                                            <label for="input-end-time"
                                                   class="form-control-label">To Year</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="inp form-control" name="end" id="input-end-time">
                                            <div class="mt-2">
                                                <label for="input-current" class="kt-checkbox kt-checkbox--brand col-6">
                                                    <input type="checkbox" id="input-current"> Current
                                                    <span></span>
                                                </label>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="input-description"
                                               class="form-control-label">Description</label>
                                        <textarea class="inp form-control" name = "description" id="input-description"></textarea>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                <button id="add-btn" onclick="add()" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Submit</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!--end::insert Modal-->
```

the order of the files is:

```
 '../../../assets/adminPanel/js/utilities.js',
 '../../../assets/adminPanel/js/request.js',
 '../../../assets/adminPanel/js/pages/resume/certificate-manager.js'
```

Comment: `insert()` accepts seven params but is called with six.

Comment: Is it intentional that `jQuery.validator.addMethod(...)` is called (x 5) every time `validationCheck()` is called? I would have thought that those methods needed to be added to the validator just once (for the life of the Axios page).

Comment: The `insert()` function needs to return its Promise. Also, the `insert(....)` call needs to be `return insert(....);`

Comment: There might be some misunderstanding about how this plugin works.   The `.addMethod()` method is supposed to get called ONE TIME to create each custom rule.  Likewise, the `.validate()` method gets called ONE TIME to initialize the plugin on the form.

Comment: thank you all, you were right, I call the initialization part just one time and use ```valid()``` to check